# How to move 4 wheeled robot

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a URDF (in Xacro format) which has 4 wheels.

I added the skid-steer Gazebo plugin and amended the joints information etc. When I exeute my launch file **/cmd_vel** is in my topics list but my model does not move in either rviz nor gazebo when I publish commands to **/cmd_vel**.

Below is my xacro file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="test_bot">

  <xacro:include filename="$(find sweep_bot)/urdf/sensors/camera.xacro"/>
  <xacro:include filename="$(find sweep_bot)/urdf/actuators/wheels.xacro"/>
  <xacro:include filename="$(find sweep_bot)/urdf/sensors/MultiCamera.xacro"/>

  <!-- body -->
  <xacro:property name="chasis_length" value="1.0"/>
  <xacro:property name="chasis_heigth" value="0.45"/>
  <xacro:property name="chasis_width" value="0.5"/>

  <link name="chasis">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <mass value="1.0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.4" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.4" iyz="0.0" izz="0.2"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual name="">
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${chasis_length} ${chasis_heigth} ${chasis_width}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0"/>
        <!-- <texture filename=""/> -->
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${chasis_length} ${chasis_heigth} ${chasis_width}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference='chasis'>
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
  </gazebo>

  <!-- WHEELS -->
  <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.1"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_length" value="0.1"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_rpy" value="1.55 0.0 0.0"/>

  <xacro:macro name="wheel" params="side position flip alt">
    <xacro:property name="wheel_xyz" value="${alt * 0.3} ${flip * 0.2} -0.25"/>

    <link name="wheel_${side}_${position}">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <mass value="1.0"/>
        <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
      </inertial>
      <visual name="">
        <origin xyz="${wheel_xyz}" rpy="${wheel_rpy}"/>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_length}"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="">
          <color rgba="1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
          <texture filename=""/>
        </material>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="${wheel_xyz}" rpy="${wheel_rpy}"/>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_length}"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>

    <gazebo reference='"wheel_${side}_${position}'>
      <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
    </gazebo>

    <joint name="body_wheel_${side}_${position}_joint" type="revolute">
      <parent link="chasis"/>
      <child link="wheel_${side}_${position}"/>
      <limit lower="0.0" upper="0.0" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
    </joint>
  </xacro:macro>
  
  <xacro:wheel side="left" position="fore" flip='1' alt='1'/>
  <xacro:wheel side="right" position="fore" flip='-1' alt='1'/>
  <xacro:wheel side="left" position="aft" flip='1' alt='-1'/>
  <xacro:wheel side="right" position="aft" flip='-1' alt='-1'/>


  <!-- SKIP STEERING -->
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="skid_steer_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive.so">
      <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
      <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
      <leftFrontJoint>body_wheel_left_fore_joint</leftFrontJoint>
      <rightFrontJoint>body_wheel_right_fore_joint</rightFrontJoint>
      <leftRearJoint>body_wheel_left_aft_joint</leftRearJoint>
      <rightRearJoint>body_wheel_right_aft_joint</rightRearJoint>
      <wheelSeparation>0.5</wheelSeparation>
      <wheelDiameter>0.2</wheelDiameter>
      <robotBaseFrame>chasis</robotBaseFrame>
      <torque>20</torque>
      <topicName>cmd_vel</topicName>
      <broadcastTF>true</broadcastTF>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
  <!--  -->

</robot>
```

And here is the simle launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

    <!-- PARAMETERS -->
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(find test_package)/urdf/testbot.xacro"/>

    <!-- RVIZ -->
    <node name='robot_state_publisher' pkg='robot_state_publisher' type='robot_state_publisher'/>
    <node name='joint_state_publisher_gui' pkg='joint_state_publisher_gui' type='joint_state_publisher_gui'/>
    <node name='rviz' pkg='rviz' type='rviz'/>

    <!-- GAZEBO -->
    <node name='gazebo' pkg='gazebo_ros' type='gazebo'/>
    <node name='sweeper_spawn' pkg='gazebo_ros' type='spawn_model' args='-urdf -model sweeper -param robot_description'/>
        
</launch>
```

I would appreciate some help.

**update:**

Thank you @tryan. I made the correction to my wheel joint i:e continous rather than rotate. But the effect was not as expected and I still need a little help.
Rather than the model moving forward, it tumbles. I attached an image below:

[image: image description]

That happens when I publish **0.1** on linear X with every other linear and angular value set to 0.
I obviously expected the wheels to move the model forward uniformly in the same linear direction.
I can confirm the coordinate frames on all the wheels are all oriented in the same direction, with X being the red line, as shown below:
[image: image description]

I tried altering only the value of linear Y instead but the model did not move at all.

I'm not sure if this behaviour is do do with my urdf model OR if it's a steer-drive plugin configuration issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367687/how-to-move-4-wheeled-robot/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2020-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As explained in the [Building a Movable Robot Model with URDF tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Movable%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF), `revolute` joints have strict motion limits.  For something like a wheel, you probably want a `continuous` joint.

---

UPDATE

It's moving, so you almost got it!  However, it appears your wheels operate on the wrong axis.  When you give it a linear x motion, the wheels tumble (rotation about the wrong axis); when you give it a linear y, there's no motion (skid steer can't move sideways).  If you give it an angular z, I expect the wheels to tumble in opposite directions (correct command, wrong axis).  As suggested in [this Gazebo answer](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/21826/how-to-use-the-gazebo_ros-skid-steer-drive-plugin/), it may help to read [the controller's source code](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/gazebo_plugins/html/gazebo__ros__skid__steer__drive_8cpp_source.html) and take an incremental approach to testing.  In this case, the controller is actually behaving as expected.

The missing piece is that you can change the axis of rotation for a `joint` with the `<axis>` element as mentioned in the [`URDF/XML/joint` documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint).  The default is rotation about the x-axis, which you observed.  What you want is rotation about the y-axis, so add `<axis>0 1 0</axis>` to your wheel `joint` definition.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2020-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2020-12-15**:
Thanks Tryan. I wasn't very familiar with the axis element and I had been trying to get the necessary orientation via the origin element. I really appreciate your help and the clarity of your explanation in the second paragraph of your update.

**Comment by [jcjmagno](https://answers.ros.org/users/65549/jcjmagno/) on 2020-12-16**:
Hi. I would like to ask if your robot is now moving forward and what did you do to make it move forward? Currently having similar issues.

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2020-12-16**:
@jcjmagno: Hi.
If your issue is exactly like mine. setting the axis of the joint should fix it. Originaally, the wheels had been trying to rotate around the x-axis which caused it to tumble in the wrong direction. Setting the the joint to rotate around the y-axis causes the robot to move "naturally" in the right direction